# Unit testing here or somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, testing

Are unit testing questions in scope for this site?  I found a stack exchange (bugoverflow.com) site geared for testers but I'm not sure of where to go for unit testing questions as this is primarily a developer activity.

PS, I referenced the site in case it adds clarity.  However, if referencing other sites isn't kosher, please feel free to edit the reference out.

Answer (score 3):

I see [more than 3000 uses of the [unit-testing] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) on Stack Overflow...I think you can safely ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing,TDD, and other aspects of ensuring the strength of the product of your programming are best discussed on stackoverflow.com.  In fact, there is a tag 'unit-testing' that currently has 3,354 questions associated.